# Fulltext search against column value?

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, match-against

I've read this:

[MySQL Fulltext search against column value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011477/mysql-fulltext-search-against-column-value)

but it is absurd, i don't understand why it is not possible doing this.

anyone knowing some workaround?

thanks

Comment: what is your engine type of table?

Comment: what problem your are exactly getting. you cant simple refer another link and saying this is absurd

Comment: Use cursor and assingn value of cursor inside against using concat, first share your requirement clearly then we can further help.

Comment: AGAINST(table1.field1) doesn't work, only works with literal strings

Comment: ive tryed CONCAT(field, " ") without success, same error

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer use it inside procedure.

Comment: @Jason_vorhees answer with an example please, my sql skills are limited! thanks!

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer see my answer, it doesnot suits in your exect case but can give you a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my old procedure, try something like this in your case too-

```
BEGIN
  declare done default 0;
  declare csv1 varchar(100);
  declare cur1 cursor for select csv from table; 
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;
  open cur1;
  repeat
  fetch cur1 into csv1;
  -
  -
  -
  -
  update company set (something) where match(csv) against(concat("'",csv1,"'"));
  until  done end repeat;
  -
  -
  close cur1;
  select * from table;
END
```

Comment: thanks! apparently this is what i'm looking for.. someone had tried if actually works for my case?

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer this is an overview of my long procedure, its working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Because the data is stored on the catalog. When you query a full text index, you are reading data from the catalog it is created, not the table the index is pointing to.

When you "populate" the catalog, you are telling your server to read data from the table and insert on the catalog. If you have a non static value, how will you read it?

Comment: I think the question is about MySQL, though I'm not sure if the principle differs.