# Single mysql query to get datas with an ID and to get related datas

Tags: mysql, json

i need to form a single mysql query to get * datas from a table with an ID, and 4 related datas which match the "title" of the first query.

**Table name:** feeditems

**Rows:**
`item_id`, `item_title`, `item_description`

To get the datas i am using

```
$related_sql = "SELECT * FROM feeditems
                WHERE feeditems.item_id='$id' LIMIT 1";
```

To get related datas i am using

```
$related_sql = "SELECT * FROM feeditems
                WHERE feeditems.item_id != '$item_row[item_id]'
                AND MATCH (feeditems.item_title)
                AGAINST ('$item_row[item_title]' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
                ORDER BY feeditems.item_id DESC LIMIT 4";
```

I need to combine this 2 queries into a single query, since i am giving out the json data of the query using the following code

```
$set = array();    
$total_records = mysql_num_rows($resouter);
if($total_records >= 1){
    while ($link = mysql_fetch_array($resouter, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $set['NewsApp'][] = $link;
    }
}
echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($set,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Else is there any way to combine the results of the above 2 queries into a single json outout using json_encode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [INNER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to link back to the same table :

```
$related_sql = "SELECT f2.item_id, f2.item_title, f2.item_description 
FROM feeditems f1
INNER JOIN feeditems f2 ON 
             f1.item_id != f2.item_id AND 
             MATCH (f2.item_title) AGAINST (f1.item_title IN BOOLEAN MODE)
WHERE f1.item_id='$id'
ORDER BY f2.item_id DESC LIMIT 4";
```

**UPDATE** : I found that this will not work since you are using `MATCH ... AGAINST`.

"The expression need not be a literal string, but it must an expression that has a constant value during query evaluation. This permits variables, for example, but rules out column names."

Look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match , http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66573 and [MySQL Fulltext search against column value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011477/mysql-fulltext-search-against-column-value)

So like lolka_polka said, use a subquery and it will work :

```
$related_sql = "SELECT item_id, item_title, item_description 
FROM feeditems
WHERE item_id != '$id' AND 
             MATCH (item_title) AGAINST ((SELECT item_title FROM feeditems
                WHERE item_id='$id' LIMIT 1) IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 4";
```

See [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9d167b/12)

**UPDATE2** : Use an [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

```
$related_sql = "(SELECT item_id, item_title, item_description 
FROM feeditems
WHERE item_id = '$id' LIMIT 1)
UNION 
(SELECT item_id, item_title, item_description 
FROM feeditems
WHERE item_id != '$id' AND 
             MATCH (item_title) AGAINST ((SELECT item_title FROM feeditems
                WHERE item_id='$id' LIMIT 1) IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 4)
ORDER BY item_id;";
```

See [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ba3e1/11)

Comment: it gives out only the 4 related datas. But its not giving out the data for the item_id. I need total 5 rows at the output. 1 with item_id='$id' and other 4 are related rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries in your query. Try this:

```
$related_sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM feeditems
 WHERE feeditems.item_id != $id 
   AND MATCH (feeditems.item_title) AGAINST ((SELECT item_title WHERE feeditems.item_id=$id) LIMIT 1 IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 ORDER 
    BY feeditems.item_id DESC
 LIMIT 4
";
```

**NOTE**

- Do not use `mysql` functions, they are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.
- You are vulnerable to sql injections. Always escsape your variables in the query, or use prepared statements.

Comment: There is no way to know if the code is vulnerable to sql injections since we don't know how `$id` is defined...

Comment: @FabienTheSolution But we know that the use of prepared statements (available under mysqli/pdo) would render it invulnerable

Comment: For this, no doubt :)

Comment: Getting the $id = abs(intval($_GET['news_id']));

Comment: Both solutions returned nothing :(